# ¿Es necesario usar init.py para los paquetes en Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿Es necesario usar un init.py para que una carpeta sea considerada un paquete en Python 3.7?

Comment: Parece que no. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3/37140173#37140173

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende de qué tipo de paquete estemos hablando.

Un paquete normal, es una carpeta dentro de la cual hay varios ficheros `.py`, que son cada uno de ellos un "módulo". Puede incluso llegar a contener una subcarpeta que sea a su vez un subpaquete. Por poner un ejemplo, pongamos que los contenidos de la carpeta son:

```
└── foo
    ├── a.py
    ├── b.py
    └── c.py
```

Como vemos, no existe el archivo `__init__.py`. Entonces, suponiendo que la carpeta `foo` está dentro de otra carpeta que forma parte del `PYTHONPATH` (o sea, que python puede importarla), los siguientes `import` funcionarán sin problemas:

```
import foo.a
from foo import b
import foo
```

Ninguno de los tres dará error bajo python3 (aunque sí lo darían bajo python2 por no exisstir `__init__.py` en la carpeta `foo`.

- `import foo.a` permitirá dentro del código hacer uso de cualquier símbolo definido en `foo/a.py`, por ejemplo `foo.a.MiClaseA` o lo que fuera.
- `from foo import b`  es análogo al anterior, pero evita tener que usar el prefijo `foo` para acceder a los símbolos de `foo/b.py`, y así puedo usar directamente `b` como espacio de nombres, así por ejemplo `b.MiClaseB`, etc
- El módulo `foo/c.py` no ha sido importado. No tengo acceso a sus símbolos.
- `import foo` no sirve de nada. Esta orden normalmente ejecutaría `foo/__init__.py`, pero ya que en este caso no existe, no hace nada. En particular **no define automáticamente los subespacios `a`, `b` o `c`**. Por tanto un intento de acceder a `foo.c` dará error (`foo.a` no lo dará porque lo importamos antes, `foo.b` tambien funcionará porque se cargó como parte del `from foo import b`)

Por tanto, salvo por el detalle de que `import foo` no ha hecho nada, ha funcionado.

Ahora bien, si añadiéramos un `__init__.py`, de modo que ahora la estructura sea:

```
└── foo
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── a.py
    ├── b.py
    └── c.py
```

entonces `import foo` ejecutaría `__init__.py` (esto es así tanto en python2 como python3).

Si `__init__.py` estuviera vacío, lo cual es válido, sería **exactamente igual que si no estuviera**. En python2 era frecuente poner un `__init__.py` vacío sólo para marcar que esa carpeta era un paquete. *En python3 esto ya no es necesario*.

Pero también podemos aprovechar y poner algo dentro de ese `__init__.py`. Típicamente este fichero se usa para inicializar ciertas variables o símbolos que queremos que se puedan importar fácilmente. Un ejemplo sencillo podría ser:

```
# Contenido de foo/__init__.py
from . import a, b, c
```

Entonces, al hacer `import foo`, ya que se ejecuta `foo/__init__.py`, se tiene que también se ejecutarán `foo/a.py`, `foo/b.py` y `foo/c.py`, y que los símbolos `a`, `b` y `c` quedarán definidos dentro del paquete `foo`, por lo que ahora, desde el programa que hizo el `import`, puedo usar `foo.a`, `foo.b` y `foo.c` sin errores.

Incluso si el programa hace `from foo import a`, se ejecutará `foo/__init__.py` y por tanto los tres módulos que éste importa.

También se puede hacer `from foo import *` (aunque no se recomienda) y eso definirá los símbolos `a`, `b` y `c` (que son módulos) en el espacio de nombres de quien hace el import.

Otro caso habitual dentro de `__init__.py` es definir una lista llamada `__all__` con los nombres de los símbolos que se quieren exportar masivamente. Por ejemplo:

```
# Otro posible contenido de foo/__init__.py
from . import a, b, c

# No queremos exportar masivamente c
__all__ = ["a", "b"]
```

Esto de la exportación masiva se refiere a que otro programa haga `from foo import *`. Ese asterisco será expandido por Python a la lista de símbolos definidos en `__all__`, por lo que en este caso el programa que haga ese import tendrá acceso a `a` y `b` pero no a `c`. Observa no obstante que eso no vale para hacer que `c` sea "privado". Ese concepto no existen Python. El programa que haga `from foo import *` no ve `c`, pero puede hacer `from foo import c` para verlo también.

Comment: muchas gracias. Fue muy buena tu explicación y útil.

Answer (score 0):

Si, el archivo **__init__.py** se sigue requiriendo para inicializar un paquete, de igual forma si tu paquete tiene subpaquetes, este debe contener también su propio archivo **__init__.py**, los archivos pueden ser archivos en blanco.

Puedes obtener mas información en su sitio:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Apartado 6.4

Comment: no es "necesario" python3 genera el archivo automaticamente si no existe